# Python/Pygame.. Trouble w/ classes

Tags: python, animation, pygame

Hey guys I have some issues while I was making my game.... I want to move my character while the image changes every "step" that it looks like an animation...

I haven been working on this for hours but the only thing I have done so far is to move the char but all images are drawn at once while moving

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    currentimageleft = 1
    gamedisplay.blit(background, (0,0))
    if currentimageleft == 1:
        gamedisplay.blit(temp1, (template_x, template_y), (g1x, g1y, box, box))
        template_x -= moveit
        currentimageleft += 1
    if currentimageleft == 2:
        gamedisplay.blit(temp1, (template_x, template_y), (g2x, g2y, box, box))
        template_x -= moveit
        currentimageleft += 1
    if currentimageleft == 3:
        gamedisplay.blit(temp1, (template_x, template_y), (g3x, g3y, box, box))
        template_x -= moveit
        currentimageleft += 1
    if currentimageleft == 4:
        gamedisplay.blit(temp1, (template_x, template_y), (g4x, g4y, box, box))
        template_x -= moveit
        currentimageleft = 1
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: here is a link to see what it looks like:   https://www.flickr.com/photos/130707619@N05/

Comment: Is it possible, that you just add the change split to your screen without refreshing background?

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more what you mean by adding the change split..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are incrementing `currentimgeleft` in each of your `if` blocks, it then triggers the next `if` block down the line. You only want one to trigger each frame, so switch the `if` to `elif` for all but the first one and then you'll have only one triggering each time the `K_LEFT` button is pressed on the keyboard. Like so

```
if currentimageleft == 1:
    # code
elif currentimageleft == 2:
    # code
...
```

However, notice that you are setting `currentimageleft` each time you enter the bigger `if` statement for the keypress. This will ensure that you *always* end up using the very first sprite of your animation. You may want to associate `currentimageleft` with a class variable by declaring it in `__init__` to be something like

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    # other code, including possible parent constructors
    self.currentleftimage = 1
    # more code
```

You would then access your variable with `self.currentimageleft` instead of `currentimageleft`. This would then allow you to use `else` or `elif` clauses on your button press detection (the outer `if` in your code snippet) to reset the `self.currentleftimage` variable back to `1` allowing you to track motion that way instead.

You may also find [this other answer on the equivalent form of `switch` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python%20%22this%20other%20question%20of%20the%20equivalent%20form%20of%20%60switch%60%20statements%20in%20Python) interesting, though several calls to `elif` clauses is also perfectly normal and may lead to more legible code in many cases.

Comment: Thx a lot bro! It worked fine!!! :D  Didn´t notice that because of the "while-loop" it always gets back to 1 T_T

Comment: @TofuDaydreamer You are quite welcome. Glad to be of service. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `elif` for the subsequent comparisons, so that only one is done per iteration.

Comment: now he moves forward but only with one of the images :(